# UPDATE statement doesn't get triggered on new server

Tags: php, mysql, foreach, newline, mysql-real-escape-string

```
foreach($article AS $key => $value)
{
    mysql_query("UPDATE articles SET description = '".mysql_real_escape_string($value)."' WHERE id = '".$key."'");
}
```

Hi guys,

I have this very simple foreach loop where I run an UPDATE query. Yeah, I know that I should use PDO but I'm just testing it so don't worry. **$key** and **$value** are not null. I've already verified that their values are the expected ones. $value contains a string with multiple **\n** (new line).

Now the script is working on my server but as soon as I try it on another server the UPDATE statement doesn't get triggered. No errors or warning. It seems that the other server doesn't like the content of **$value**. In fact if I replace $value for example with "abc" it works. So I'm here trying to understand what the problem. The \n? The mysql_real_escape_string? What should I do to debug this issue?

Comment: If you're just learning PHP, please, do not learn the obsolete `mysql_query` interface. It's awful and is being removed in future versions of PHP. A modern replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/). A guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) can help explain best practices. Always be absolutely **sure** your user parameters are [properly escaped](http://bobby-tables.com/php) or you will have severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Comment: Try to read error logs.

Comment: so test for errors, don't just assume success: `mysql_query(...) or die(mysql_error())`.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, it was my bad. The script works. It was due to an incredibly complicated and long to explain thing related to a CDN cache of my cloud instance. What the hell! Sorry.

Answer (score -1):

```
foreach($article AS $key => $value)
{
    mysql_query("UPDATE articles SET description='{mysql_real_escape_string($value)}' WHERE id='{$key}'");
}
```

Try this